# Microsoft.Net.Compilers package breaks when updated

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I was wondering what causes the Nuget package Microsoft.Net.Compilers to try to use .NET 4.6 after updating it to its latest version?

The server that my intranet site is being deployed to only has .NET 4.5 and when I update the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package and deploy the site I get an error that says its trying to reference .NET 4.6 even though in my project setting the version is set to .NET 4.5. Is there a fix for this problem or should I just not update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rosyln compiler *itself* has a dependency on the .NET Framework. This build-time dependency is irrespective of the Framework version *your* code is targetting.

The [Nuget page for Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) states (at version 2.8.0):

> This package can be used to compile code targeting any platform, but
>   can only be run using the desktop .NET 4.6+ Full Framework.

If you cannot install a newer version of the Framework your best option is to use an earlier version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers. The newest version I can find which appears to support .NET 4.5 is [2.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/2.0.1).